# Change List elements from info in Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,int> infoDic
```

and a list

```
List<Info> infoList
```

Info object has 2 properties: InfoText and InfoInt

I want to check if infoList has any Info object where Info.InfoText equals infoDic.Key
and if so i want to instantiate Info.InfoInt to infoDic.Value

*EDIT*

```
   var test=  from t in infoList
         join x in infoDic
         on t.InfoText equals x.Key
         select new Info {InfoText =t.InfoText , InfoInt=x.Value }
```

Any help?
Ty

Comment: Please show your code so far so we can correct it. If you have no code, please tell us why.

Comment: code added.. remove the down vote plz xD

Comment: And what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: i was looking for a different way to do it, or more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// IEnumerable<Info>
var items = infoList.Where(i => infoDic.ContainsKey(i.InfoText))
                    .Select(e => new Info
                            {
                                InfoInt = infoDic[e.InfoText],
                                InfoText = e.InfoText
                            });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if infoList has any Info object where Info.InfoText
>   equals infoDic.Key

may be something like this:

```
var ifAny = infoList.Any(info=>infoDic.ContainsKey(info.InfoText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool contains = infoList.Any(i => infoDic.ContainsKey(i.InfoText));
```

But because of your second requirement:

```
Info info = infoList.FirstOrDefault(i => infoDic.ContainsKey(i.InfoText));
if(info != null)
{
    infoDic[info.InfoText] = info.InfoInt;
    //or the other way around(it's not that clear)
    info.InfoInt = infoDic[info.InfoText];
}
```